# Remove adjacent similar value in array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

i have array like this

```
{
0: "abc"
1: "abc"
5: "abc"
6: "def"
7: "ghk"
8: "abc"
}
```

i want to remove adjecent similar value. It like

```
{
0: "abc"
6: "def"
7: "ghk"
8: "abc"
}
```

i try to use

```
$p = array_unique($array);
```

but it become

```
{
0: "abc"
6: "def"
7: "ghk"
}
```

i don't want remove 8: "abc" because it's not adjacent similar value. 
Can i use any function to do that? thanks :)

Comment: why 'it's not adjacent similar value'?

Comment: Yes, you need to make own function. because array_unique function find adjacent from all array values, not, as you want, only consequent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$myArray = array(
    0 => "abc",
    1 => "abc",
    5 => "abc",
    6 => "def",
    7 => "ghk",
    8 => "abc",
);

$previous = NULL;
$newArray = array_filter(
    $myArray,
    function ($value) use (&$previous) {
        $p = $previous;
        $previous = $value;
        return $value != $p;
    }
);

var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: You should probably use `!==` to prevent an empty string from being removed at the beginning of the array (since if the first item in the array is falsy, it will always be removed with this code). Alternatively, use another variable in addition to `$previous` that just stores whether or not to compare at all (false for the first item, true for all subsequent items). This is better since it won't remove `NULL` at the beginning of the array either.

Comment: True enough, it was just a `quick and dirty` solution to OP's problem, with assumption that he'd always have simple string values in his array; but it's easy enough to modify to suit that specific situation

Comment: Understood - you still got my upvote. Just wanted to add the additional clarification for the OP or future readers.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
$myArray = array(
        0 => "abc",
        1 => "abc",
        5 => "abc",
        6 => "def",
        7 => "ghk",
        8 => "abc",
);

$newArray = array();
$previous = '';
foreach ($myArray as $myArray_value) {

    if ($previous !== $myArray_value)
        $newArray[] = $myArray_value;

    $previous = $myArray_value;

}

print_r($newArray);
```

Hope this helps you :)